# Windows Azure Active Directory -> Set password for the user

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am referring OrgChart Example here: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WindowsAzureAD-GraphAPI-Sample-OrgChart

It has predefined set of properties that can be set at the time of user creation.

Can someone tell me how do I add Password property when creating a user

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for [Create User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn130117.aspx). In your request body, it would look like this to set a password for the user:

```
{
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "displayName": "Alex Wu",
    "mailNickname": "AlexW",
    "passwordProfile": { "password" : "Test1234", "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false },
    "userPrincipalName": "Alex@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

You can also check out the docs for [Password profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151670.aspx) to see what limitations exist for setting the password.

Comment: This is correct. All I want is to include Password and ForceChangePasswordNextLogin in the predefined list of attributes. here is the predefined list of attributes given in OrgChart code sample :   private static string[] standardAttributes = { "displayName", "jobTitle", "userPrincipalName", "mailNickname", "managerUserPrincipalName" };

Comment: Are you saying you want the sample modified to show "password" and "forceChangePasswordNextLogin" fields in the form on the web page?

Comment: Yes. thats correct. Because I have requirement where I want to add values to extension properties as well as the password for the users. Thanks!
Suggestions to do this are welcome.